# SQL - Two CHECK condition in one Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements, create-table

I'm trying to implement two `CHECK` conditions in one table -

This way it won't work:

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
    ex_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    age TINYINT CHECK (age > 21),
    parent_age TINYINT CHECK (parent_age > age) -- fail on this one
);
```

Checking the Microsot Docs "Creating and Modifying CHECK Constraints"

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vendors 
(
    VendorID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    VendorName nvarchar (50), 
    CreditRating tinyint
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Vendors 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Vendor_CreditRating
        CHECK (CreditRating >= 1 AND CreditRating <= 5)
```

I didn't understand what the `CK_Vendor_CreditRating` is, but I tried :

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
    ex_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    age TINYINT CHECK (age > 21),
    parent_age TINYINT 
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.example 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_example_parent_age
        CHECK (parent_age > age)
```

Close - but I still get an error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 7

Will be glad for any suggestions.

Comment: A two column constraint is a table constraint, and should be a separate "item" in the CREATE TABLE. `...parent_age TINYINT, CONSTRAINT CK_example_parent_age CHECK (parent_age > age)`.

Comment: Your code works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36a5b32fbf79a52ced28aeecf5b2a48b.

Comment: BTW, you should never store age, because people tend to become older every year and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date of birth instead.